# Swift - Unable to read multiple characteristics over BLE

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

My application is able to successfully subscribe to both characteristics over BLE but it only reads data from one of the characteristics. The following is my code that is able to successfully read a single characteristic but not multiple.

```
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    
    guard characteristic == rxCharacteristic,
        let data:Data = characteristic.value
        else { return }

    var myFloatArray = Array<Float>(repeating: 0, count: data.count/MemoryLayout<Float>.stride)
    myFloatArray.withUnsafeMutableBytes { data.copyBytes(to: $0) }
```

Comment: The `guard` statement ensures only `rxCharacteristic` data is processed.  If you want to process data from other characteristic, you'll need to replace it with a `switch characteristic` statement.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you mean by switch characteristic statement

Comment: Like that: `switch characteristic { case rxCharacteristic: /* something */; case differentCharacteristic: /* something different */; }`